# wildfly-9.0.2.Final - EJB invocations from a remote server

Tags: jsp, ejb-3.0, wildfly

I am looking up and invoking EJBs deployed on an WildFly server(destination server) instance from another WildFly server instance. To do this i am following link - 'https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-EJBinvocationsfromaremoteserver'

test.jar has been deployed at destination server. Following are the deployment logs.

```
16:34:46,545 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0010: Stopping weld service for deployment test.jar
16:34:46,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment test.jar (runtime-name: test.jar) in 40ms
16:34:46,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "test.jar" (runtime-name: "test.jar")
16:34:46,588 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment test.jar
16:34:46,595 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-5) JNDI bindings for session bean named TestHelperBean in deployment unit deployment "test.jar" are as follows:

java:global/test/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperLocal
java:app/test/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperLocal
java:module/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperLocal
java:global/test/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote
java:app/test/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote
java:module/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote
java:jboss/exported/test/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote

16:34:46,610 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: test.jar
16:34:46,614 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment test.jar
16:34:46,834 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-3) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "test.jar" with deployment "test.jar"
```

Stateless session-bean has been deployed at destination server.

```
package moc.test.ejb.session;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Local;
@Stateless
@Remote (TestHelperRemote.class)
@Local(TestHelperLocal.class)
public class TestHelperBean implements TestHelperRemote,TestHelperLocal
{
public boolean testFunction() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("[TestHelperBean][testFunction]");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {}
    return false;
}
}
```

Following is client code invoking the test.jarbean instance.

```
package com.testmodule.pojo;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote;
public class Test { 
public void getDbConnection(){
    try{
        final Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();            
        props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); // setup the ejb: namespace URL factory         
        final Context context = new javax.naming.InitialContext(props); // create the InitialContext
        final TestHelperRemote bean = (TestHelperRemote) context.lookup("ejb:" + "" + "/" + "test" + "/"
                + "" + "/" + "TestHelperBean" + "!" + moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote.class.getName());
        bean.testFunction();                        
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

But at run time following error occurred

```
15:58:48,972 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:test, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@46e20ef9
15:58:48,973 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:774)
15:58:48,974 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
15:58:48,974 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
15:58:48,975 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
15:58:48,975 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
15:58:48,976 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
```

why this error has been occurred?

Comment: Instead of using the *ejb:* namespace, try using the *remote* namespace as explained on [WildFly's Remote JNDI Reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Remote+JNDI+Reference+Update+Draft) documentation. Notice that the *http-remoting* client assumes JNDI names in remote lookups are relative to **java:jboss/exported** namespace, a lookup of an absolute JNDI name will fail. Therefore you should do the lookup on `test/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote`.

Comment: @aribeiro...After using remote namespace lookup JNDI, NameNotFoundException occurred....javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: test/TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.test."TestHelperBean!moc.test.ejb.session.TestHelperRemote"

Comment: Could you please update your question with the properties you've used to establish this latest lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client (i.e. the code trying to invoke a service) is on Wildfly instance 1 where as your server (i.e. where your ejb is deployed) is on instance 2. Let's assume that instance 1 is running on default port 8080 while instance 2 is running on port 8180.

The [link you used in your question](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-EJBinvocationsfromaremoteserver), has a section called *Create a security realm on the client server* that describes the various steps needed for creating "outbound-socket-binding" and "remote-outbound-connection." I am not sure if you have already done that or  not. Without this step, the application on instance 1 does not know how to connect to service on instance 2.

If you do not want to go the configuration route, there is a good write up on [stackoverflow question - wildfly-to-wildfly-ejb-client-without-remote-outbound-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178329/wildfly-to-wildfly-ejb-client-without-remote-outbound-connections). This technique works for me and might be of help to you in finding your own solution. With this solution, you can specify the server address, port (in this example would be 8180), username, and password needed to connect to the ejb that is hosted on the 2nd Wildfly instance.