# EJB remote invokation from Wildfly to Jboss5.x server

Tags: ant, ejb-3.0, wildfly, jboss5.x

Enviornment - Source server@Wildlfy_9.0.2.Final,Destination_Server@Jboss5.x, EJB3.0,BuildingTool@ant

1.[Wildfly to Wildfly EJB client without remote-outbound-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178329/wildfly-to-wildfly-ejb-client-without-remote-outbound-connections)

2.https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-EJBinvocationsfromaremoteserver

From above two link i have successfully remote EJB lookup for Wildfly_9.0.2.Final to Wildfly_9.0.2.Final server. After this i want to replace destination server to Jboss 5.x server. I have spent hours looking for tutorials on Google. However I cannot seem to find anything that holds the hand. Can anyone direct me to some link?

Comment: Can't you change your EJB, in JBoss 5, to be provided as a web service?

Comment: Can you direct me to some link for replacing of ejb to web-service...and can we not call EJBs from Wildlfy_9.0.2.Final to Jboss 5.x(between different version of jboss server)?

Comment: I've found a [JBoss forum thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/230003?tstart=0) where is discussed the possibility of accessing a JBoss AS X instance from a different JBoss AS Y instance. Take a look into it. It may help you. Also, if you're willing to change your EJB to a web service, can't you simply upgrade your JBoss 5 version to WildFly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extension for this as the JNDI lokup has changed between AS5  (jnp) and WildFly. I don't know what is thge current status of https://github.com/jboss-set/jboss-as-legacy but this was the goal of this extension.